# how to call functions from a tcl main script?

Tags: syntax, package, tcl, proc, method-call

I'm going through the `Tcl` tutorials on packaging.  How are these methods called?

package:

```
package provide weather  1.0
package require Tcl      8.5

namespace eval ::tutstack {
}

proc ::tutstack::hello {} {
    puts "hello world"
}


proc ::tutstack::sum {arg1 arg2} {
    set x [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}];
    return $x
}

proc ::tutstack::helloWorld {arg1} {
    return "hello plus arg"
}
```

from main:

```
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/api

package require weather 1.0



tutstack::hello

set A 3
set B 4

puts [tutstack::sum $A $B]


puts [tutstack::hello "fred"]
```

error:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$ tclsh main.tcl 
hello world
7
wrong # args: should be "tutstack::hello"
    while executing
"tutstack::hello "fred""
    invoked from within
"puts [tutstack::hello "fred"]"
    (file "main.tcl" line 15)
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet$
```

Comment: you have defined `hello` to take no arguments. `helloWorld` takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops:

```
lappend auto_path /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/spawnTelnet/telnet/api

package require weather 1.0



tutstack::hello

set A 3
set B 4

puts [tutstack::sum $A $B]


puts [tutstack::helloWorld "fred"]
```

thanks glenn